# How do we pivot data in R and add a calculation afterwards

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to pivot a dataset longer and after that operation I need to add a calculation.  The challenge I am having is that the calculation will be specific to each row potentially.

So given this dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(
  person = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "Jen","Zar"),
  filed_taxes = c(1,0,1,0,0),
  required_to_file_taxes =c(1,1,1,0,0),
  bought_items = c(1,1,1,0,1),
  required_to_buy_items = c(1,1,1,1,1),
  took_vacation = c(1,0,0,1,1),
  required_to_take_vacation = c(1,1,1,1,1)
)
```

The columns that begin with "required" will be used to calculate a percent of total in that relative category.

So the output would look something like this:

```
Measure        Completed     % Completed
filed_taxes        2             66%
bought_items       4             80%
took_vacation      3             60%
```

I tried to `pivot_longer` then `pivot_wider` to calculate the percent since they are essentially rowwise calculations and then `pivot_longer` again for the final output, but that didn't work.

Any thoughts or tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I count how many 1s appear in each column, pivot longer, convert the column name to a pair of values specifying either observed/required or the behavior in question, and then pivot wider again.

```
library(tidyverse)
df |>
  pivot_longer(-person) |>
  count(name, wt = value) |>
  mutate(req = if_else(str_detect(name, "required"), "required", "observed"),
         name = case_when(
    name %>% str_detect("items") ~ "buy items",
    name %>% str_detect("taxes") ~ "file taxes",
    name %>% str_detect("vacation") ~ "take vacation"
  )) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = req, values_from = n) |>
  mutate(pct = observed / required)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  name          observed required   pct
  <chr>            <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 buy items            4        5 0.8  
2 file taxes           2        3 0.667
3 take vacation        3        5 0.6
```

Alternatively, if we know the columns are all arranged in pairs of observed/required, we can use those positions to get essentially the same output:

```
df |>
  pivot_longer(-person) |>
  mutate(pair_num = (row_number()-1) %/% 2, .by = person) |>
  mutate(req = if_else(str_detect(name, "required"), "required", "observed")) |>
  mutate(name = first(name), .by = c(person, pair_num)) |>
  count(name, req, wt = value) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = req, values_from = n) |>
  mutate(pct = observed / required)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  name          observed required   pct
  <chr>            <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 bought_items         4        5 0.8  
2 filed_taxes          2        3 0.667
3 took_vacation        3        5 0.6
```

Comment: This definitely works for this dataset and addresses my desired output.  The challenge when I apply to my real dataset, there are over 500 measures ("buy items", file taxes", etc) so using that mutate to manually create the names will be challenging.    Is there another option to create the names more dynamically?

Comment: Are the columns always positioned next to each other, with the required number following the observed number? If so, you could pair the columns up front...

Comment: I've updated my answer on the presumption your data is arranged this way. If it's not, you have a more difficult problem.

Comment: I think this will work.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

in base R you could do:

```
colSums(df[-1]) |>
   tapply(sub(".*_", "", names(df)[-1]),
          \(x)setNames(c(x, x[1]/x[2]), c('observed','required', 'pct')))|>
   array2DF()

      Var1 observed required       pct
1    items        4        5 0.8000000
2    taxes        2        3 0.6666667
3 vacation        3        5 0.6000000
```

---

```
stack(colSums(df[-1]))|>
   transform(name = sub(".*_", "", ind))|>
   aggregate(values~name, \(x) setNames(c(x, x[1]/x[2]), c('obs', 'req', 'pct')))|>
   do.call(what = data.frame)

      name values.obs values.req values.pct
1    items          4          5  0.8000000
2    taxes          2          3  0.6666667
3 vacation          3          5  0.6000000
```

---

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  rename_with(~str_c('Observed_', .x), !starts_with(c('required','person')))%>%
  pivot_longer(-person, names_to = c('.value', 'Measure'), 
               names_pattern = '([^_]+)_.*?([^_]+)$')%>%
  summarise(Observed = sum(Observed), 
            Required = sum(required),
            `%Completed` = Observed/Required,
            .by = Measure)

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  Measure  Observed Required `%Completed`
  <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>
1 taxes           2        3        0.667
2 items           4        5        0.8  
3 vacation        3        5        0.6
```

Comment: This does what is needed as well!